# Getting 500 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am using JQuery and Ajax to interface with an ASP.Net web service. Here is the Jquery code:

```
$.jrpc = function(url, id, method, params, success, error) {
    var request = $.json_stringify({
       'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': method,
        'params': params, 'id': id});
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: "json=" + encodeURIComponent(request),
        success: success,
        error: error,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        //timeout: 1,
        type: 'POST'});
};
```

Here is the web service code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class Access : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string EntryMethod(string json)
    {
        Requests d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Requests>(json);
        Response resp = new Response();
        resp.jsonrpc = d.jsonrpc;
        resp.result = "Got the call!";
        resp.id = d.id;
        resp.error = null;
        JavaScriptSerializer response = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string r = response.Serialize(resp);

        return r;
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

[AJAX] error - Server reponse is: 
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: json.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

Using the ASP.Net webservice test page, here are my headers and request string:
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2012 19:47:16 GMT
Content-Length: 149
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Connection: Close

json=%7B%22jsonrpc%22%3A%222.0%22%2C%22method%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22id%22%3A1%7D

And here are the headers/request string of my Ajax call which is not working:
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2012 19:47:09 GMT
Content-Length: 1062
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
jsonerror: true
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Connection: Close

json=%7B%22jsonrpc%22%3A%222.0%22%2C%22method%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22id%22%3A1%7D

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? I've tried googling it, but none of the results have really helped me.

Edit:

If I use:
    data: "{'jsonrpc':'2.0','method':'test','params':[],'id':1}",

I get this error:
[AJAX] error - Server reponse is: 
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027json\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

If I use:
    data: "json={'jsonrpc':'2.0','method':'test','params':[],'id':1}",

I get this error:
[AJAX] error - Server reponse is: 
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: json.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

Comment: It seems like you code is having an issue deserializing what you are sending to it, can you post the actual json you are sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change 
     data: "json=" + encodeURIComponent(request),
to
      data: "{json: '" + encodeURIComponent(request)+"'}",

see sample code

```
  $.ajax("WebService.asmx/EntryMethod", {
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType: "json",
        type: "POST", data: "{json:'value'}", success: function (r) { alert(r); },
        error: function (e) { alert(e); }
    });
```

Comment: Holy crap that did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the 'json=' from the data property, and making sure encodeURIComponent(request) is a json object, which I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: Change:

data: request,

I get this error: {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027json\u0027.","StackTrace":"

Comment: is there any way to post on here the json data you are posting?

Comment: Try to comment out the deserialization and everything else in the class and just leave return "1"; and see if you get a 1 on the client side; that'll help pinpoint the problem. Either a json serialization problem or an ajax setup problem. The URL is usually a common source of error if it's an ajax setup issue.

Comment: instead of encoding the data, can you just hardcode and test this: json={'jsonrpc':'2.0','method':'test','params':[],'id':1}

Comment: I put a break line in the very first line of the class, and it never makes it to the break line. Also, I replaced the contents of the class with return "true" and i still got the error.

Comment: Different error. I updated my question. Look at the bottom of it to see the errors.